# Change Chrome extension tab title

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension create a tab using the API

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  'url': other_extension_url
})
```

The url is the the url of another extension and looks like:

```
chrome-extension://ext_id_goes_here/url
```

I would like to change the the title of the newly created tab (`document.title`).

I tried to do it using content script but as far as I understand there is no way to use content script with url that looks like `chrome-extension://`

Is there an any other way to do that?

Comment: have you tried with the windows api (not tabs)

Comment: No I did not. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: nevermind, i looked it up and its not possible. In case its useful to others, you can use chrome.windows.create, and in the callback you can chrome.windows.update(window.id, ... but title is not a valid option there. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that, since security model will not allow you to access other extensions' pages.

The title is set by the document itself, and cannot be modified by `tabs` API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="chrome-extension://extension_id/page.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Note I haven't tried it from within an extension html but it did work from a html file:// opening an extension page in the iframe.

Based on this, you can have a single "wrapper" page that receives the title and the iframe url as a url parameter and updates its DOM to change the title and iframe src.