# Change tab title without blanket permissions in Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I have been working on a Chrome extension, that must be able to change the title of any tab, whether it is active or not.

Since the `chrome.tabs.update` API doesn't allow setting the title of tabs, I currently achieve this by executing a content script that sets `document.title` on the top-level frame of the tab, resulting in the need for extremely wide permissions in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [ "tabs", "*://*/", "file://*"]
```

With this, the title can be changed on most tabs, except for internal protocols (`chrome...://`).

For what the extension is doing, this is asking for *a lot* of trust. With these permissions the extension should in principle be able to steal any and all data on all websites, if it ever gets compromised.

Is there any way to change the title of tabs, that doesn't require asking the user for this level of trust? E.g., is it possible to limit what content scripts are allowed to do?

Note that a major but soft constraint is the need to be able to change the title of *inactive* tabs. I could drop this if it allows significantly limiting the permissions, but it would degrade the functionality.

The change must be possible without user interaction, so the `activeTab` permission won't work.

### Similar questions

The 5-years-old question [Change Chrome extension tab title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089911/change-chrome-extension-tab-title) seems similar, but it asks for a different detail (extending the permissions of content scripts rather than reducing them), and the APIs and security models have changed significantly over these past 5 years, making it essentially obsolete.

Comment: There's no alternative method.

Comment: ... is what I do not want as a reply, but I expect as much :/ @wOxxOm

Comment: *"For what the extension is doing, this is asking for a lot of trust"* - that's a really standard permission set found in basically 90% of extension, except the `file://*` URL maybe, which is strange that you would need.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It is needed to be able to apply the change of title when local files are opened in the browser, e.g. PDFs. Maybe I need still more; Actually I can't find `*://*/` in the documentation, so I'm not sure what exactly it allows, except that it allows `http://*/` and `https://*/` but not `file://*/`, and that access to `chrome...://*/` *cannot* be given by design.

Comment: Yeah I know what `file://` is needed for, I just find it strange that you would want to change the title under such URLs.